# release:prepare does not execute in child module

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I have a parent project with two modules. In my parent pom I have:

```xml
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                <useReleaseProfile>true</useReleaseProfile>
                <releaseProfiles>complete</releaseProfiles>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and in my first module pom:

```xml
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <preparationGoals>clean replacer:replace scm:checkin</preparationGoals>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
```

my problem: *preparationGoals* in my first module pom will not execute when I run **mvn release:prepare** in my parent pom.
What should I do to execute *preparationGoals* in my first module?
(*replacer* and *scm* plugins exist in my first module pom)